# MutationObserver in JSDOM fails because parameter 1 is not of type Node

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom, mutation-observers

I am trying to test a simple JavaScript single page application using JSDOM and Jest.

For our purposes here, index.html is a simple html document that contains the tag `<div id="app-root"></div>` and index.js, which is loaded via a `<script>` tag in index.html, adds a new `<div>` tag inside of the `app-root` that looks like this: `<div class="my-embed"></div>`. So my final HTML when this runs is:

```
<div id="app-root">
<div class="my-embed"></div>
</div>
```

With the `#app-root` always being present and `.my-embed` being present after the `<script>` is executed.

I'm trying to test this by loading the HTML in with `runScripts: 'dangerously'` and then verifying that the new `<div>` is added.

Here's my test script:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'), 'utf8');

let dom
let container

function waitForElm(parentElm, selector) {
  console.log(parentElm);
  console.log(parentElm.outerHTML);
  console.log(selector);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (parentElm.querySelector(selector)) {
      return resolve(parentElm.querySelector(selector));
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      if (parentElm.querySelector(selector)) {
        resolve(parentElm.querySelector(selector));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(parentElm, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });
}

describe('index.html', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html, { runScripts: 'dangerously', resources: "usable" })
  })

  it('adds a tag', async () => {
    container = dom.window.document.body.querySelector("#app-root")
    const elm = await waitForElm(container, '.my-embed');
    console.log(elm)
    expect(container.querySelector('.my-embed')).not.toBeNull()
  });

})
```

When I run this it keeps erroring out that "TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." But as far as I can tell, the `parentElm` I'm passing in *is* an HTML node.

```
$> npx jest
  console.log
    waiting

      at VirtualConsole.onMethodCall (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:22:29)

  console.log
    HTMLDivElement {}

      at log (src/__tests__/index.text.js:12:11)

  console.log
    <div id="app-root"></div>

      at log (src/__tests__/index.text.js:13:11)

  console.log
    .my-embed

      at log (src/__tests__/index.text.js:14:11)
```

What am I missing here? Why isn't the mutation observer treating the HTMLDivElement {} it's being passed as a node?

Comment: "*But as far as I can tell, the parentElm I'm passing in is an HTML node.*" you're passing `parentElm.body` which isn't.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had an extraneous `.body` in there from one of my many permutations of trying things. I have removed that as well as removed the extra `container = dom.window.document.body` that was unneeded. But the result is the same. 

When I `console.log(parentElm)` it tells me it is an `HTMLDivElement {}`. Is that not considered a node somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I hit into the same issue. There were implicitly two distinct JSDOM instances: one that was instantiated explicitly per test (i.e. `new JSDOM()`) and one that was [injected globally by `jest-environment-jsdom`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/28d32c6a1e48f1e4c946a8e6adbe2ae9af4103e3/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/src/index.ts#L17).

When calling `new MutationObserver()`, the implicit global instance of JSDOM was used. However, all the objects passed in were generated by the local instance. This is disallowed by JSDOM -- see the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3331). So in effect, the issue isn't that the parameter isn't a `Node`, it's that it's a `Node` from the wrong DOM.

To work around this, ensure that the `MutationObserver` being used is coming from the same JSDOM instance as the DOM nodes. This can be achieved by replacing `new MutationObserver()` with `new dom.window.MutationObserver()`.

The downside of this is that you now have to pass the JSDOM (or at least its `window`) around. Alternatively, you could use the global instance everywhere and set its HTML through another method (e.g. `document.write()` or `document.documentElement.innerHTML = ...`). The viability of this is going to depend on the exact use-case, though.